# users unable to login to Plone site

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

Here is the problem that I'm having.  Often times, I cannot login to my Plone site.  Other users have the same issue as well.  Basically what happens is that when I click "Log In", the web page just refreshes but it doesn't log me in.  In order to correct this problem, I had to clear the browser history and cookies in order to log in successfully.  Sometimes I had to do this a few times in order to work.  I would like at least 50% of the time I had to clear the history before I can login.  Other times, it just works and it logs me in without any issue.

This problem started quite some time ago, perhaps almost a year now.  I just never had time to look into it.  However it seems like this problem is related to newer version of web browsers because I never had this problem before around one year ago.

I'm running Plone version 4.0.4.  Can anyone suggest how I should troubleshoot this problem?  Should I upgrade a particular component within my Plone setup?

FYI, I'm using the building authentication component and not anything external like LDAP.  I manage my users in Site Setup -> Users and Groups.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you have a front end proxy server or cache which might be eating cookies (your login cookie).

Comment: Can you get a a HTTP request / response dumps from the web browser Web Developer Tools Network tab.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you haven't got any extra authentication plugins operating? This sounds like mis-configured session-based authentication among ZEO clients that aren't sharing their session database.

Comment: @SteveM plone doesn't use session-based authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Things to look into:

- go to /acl_users/session/manage_propertiesForm and check the settings here to make sure they make sense
- check cookie settings for if they are valid on non-ssl and that you are logging in via ssl urls.
- use a web browser web inspector(like chrome) and inspect that login cookies are set properly after you're logged in(look for the __ac cookie)
- Finally, look into your caching. If you're using plone.app.caching, make sure to NOT cache for logged in users. If you're overriding caching at the web server, make sure you're not caching when the __ac cookie is present.
- If you're not caching at the web server, make sure cache headers for the browser are also getting set appropriately
- inspecting caching will also require using a browser to inspect the headers getting returned